# Is bounded-$\mathcal L_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$ significantly different from $\mathcal L_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, compactness, infinitary-logic

Take the language $\mathcal L(=,\in)_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$, if we restrict infinite quantification strings, i.e. of the forms $``(\forall v_i)_{i \in \omega}"; ``(\exists v_i)_{i \in \omega}"$, to bounded forms, that is $``\forall v_0 \in x, \forall v_1 \in x,..."$ and $``\exists v_0 \in x , \exists v_1 \in x,..."$ abbreviated as $``(\forall v_i \in x)_{i \in \omega}"; ``(\exists v_i \in x)_{i \in \omega}"$ respectively, or even if we further demand the bound to be  a definable constant or the value of a function. Call the resulting language as "*bounded*-$\mathcal L(=,\in)_{\omega_1, \omega_1}$", and denote it by $\mathcal L(=,\in)_{\omega_1, [\omega_1]}$

> How would $\mathcal L(=,\in)_{\omega_1, [\omega_1]}$ differ from  $\mathcal L(=,\in)_{\omega_1, \omega_1}$ as regards basic properties of logic like Completeness, Compactness, etc..

As a clear example, if to $\mathcal L(=,\in)_{\omega_1, [\omega_1]}$ we add all axioms of $\sf ZFC$ written, as usual, in the fragment $\mathcal L(=,\in)_{\omega,\omega}$ and suppose we add an axiom of Foundation but in a bounded form, that is:

$\textbf{Foundation: } \\\forall \alpha \,  (\forall v_i \in V_\alpha)_{i \in \omega} \, \exists x: \bigvee_{i \in \omega} (x=v_i) \land \bigwedge_{i \in \omega} (v_i \not \in x)$

Would that theory be different from theory written in $\mathcal L(=,\in)_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$, axiomatized by $\sf ZFC$ axioms in $\mathcal L(=,\in)_{\omega,\omega}$ , and Foundation written as above but unbounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your new formulation of foundation is equivalent to the corresponding unbounded form. The reason is that every failing instance of the unbounded formulation will lead to a failing instance of the bounded formulation, since if there is a countable collection of $v_i$ with no $\in$-minimal element, then by the usual ZFC axioms it follows that $v_0$ is in some $V_\alpha$, and so the $v_i$ that appear within this $V_\alpha$ will fall under the bounded form, and an $\in$-minimal for that part of the family will be $\in$-minimal for the whole family since $V_\alpha$ is transitive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, this equivalence is proved in the unbounded language, since in the bounded language you cannot even express the unbounded form of Foundation. The two theories differ in the underlying logic, their closures are ought not to be the same, the first cannot have unbounded infinite sentences as theorems, the second allows unbounded ones. But, all in all, are they equivalent as far as consistency strength is concerned?

Comment: I'm arguing that the models in which the unbounded form of foundation fails are the very same models in which the bounded form fails. So they express the same meaning--the two formulations are equivalent. (Meanwhile, I find it misguided/meaningless/problematic to speak of consistency strength in the context of infinitary logic, since we have no sound and complete effective proof system.)